# How can I index pointer type struct array inside struct?

Tags: pointers, indexing, struct

In the header file, I declared some structs like below

```
typedef struct ScopeStack {
    ste *entry[SCOPE_STACK_SIZE];
    int top;
} ScopeStack;

typedef struct ste {
    char *name;
    decl *declaration;
    struct ste *prev;
} ste;

typedef struct decl{
    int declclass; /* DECL class: VAR, CONST, FUNC, TYPE */
    decl *type; /* VAR, CONST: pointer to its TYPE decl*/
    int value; /* CONST: value of integer constant */
    float real_value; /* CONST: value of float constant */
    ste *formals; /* FUNC: pointer to formal argument list */
    decl *returntype; /* FUNC: pointer to return TYPE decl*/
    int typeclass; /* TYPE: type class: INT, array, ptr, … */
    decl *elementvar;/* TYPE (array): ptrto element VAR decl*/
    int num_index; /* TYPE (array): number of elements */
    ste *fieldlist; /* TYPE (struct): ptrto field list */
    decl *ptrto; /* TYPE (pointer): type of the pointer */
    int size; /* ALL: size in bytes */
    ste **scope; /* VAR: scope when VAR declared */
    decl *next; /* For list_of_variablesdeclarations */
} decl;
```

If I declare variable like

```
ScopeStack *scopestack;
```

I'm curious whether I can access ste* type array inside scopestack by indexing

```
scopestack->entry[scopestack->top];
```

Comment: Sure you can, why wouldn't you be able to?  Provided, of course, that you have initialized all the pointers to point to something.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `scopestack` and `entry` are initialized in your code, then you can access the array entry (like this `scopestack->entry[scopestack->top];` if that's what you want) without any problem.
Don't let the **`scopestack->top`** part of the statement confuse you.

What you are trying to do is basiccally:

```
index = scopestack->top;
spopestack->entry[index];
```

which is the same as `scopestack->entry[scopestack->top];` with one more step.